# Ignore Y axis or keep Y axis as 0 when using transform.forward?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Is it possible to keep Y axis static or keep it as the same value when using transform.forward function? 
So that the object is moved in X and Z axis and is not affected in the Y axis.

```
 Ray ray;
            RaycastHit info;

            ray = new Ray(ObjectPosition.transform.position, ObjectPosition.transform.forward);
            bool hit = Physics.Raycast(ray, out info);
```

Comment: Just use a variable and set the y to 0 ? `Vector3 temp = ObjectPosition.transform.forward; temp.y = 0;`

Comment: Point of interest, `Vector3.ProjectOnPlane()` does exactly this but for any given normal. See https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.ProjectOnPlane.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either:

```
Ray ray;
RaycastHit info;
Vector3 dir = ObjectPosition.transform.forward;
dir.y = 0; // as @Jichael suggested

ray = new Ray(ObjectPosition.transform.position, dir);
bool hit = Physics.Raycast(ray, out info);
```

Or:

if you need the player to stay on the same y-level, you could check "contraint / freeze axis:y" on the rigid body settings.